# timedelta to 12 pm CET

Tags: python, datetime, timezone, pytz

I am trying to get the remaining time to 12 pm Europe/Berlin on a machine with unknown local timezone (GitHub actions).

I have a function that should return a timedelta, with the remaining time until 12 pm.

```py
import datetime
import pytz

def get_twelve_pm():
    cest = pytz.timezone('Europe/Berlin')

    now = datetime.datetime.now(tz=cest)
    twelve_pm = datetime.datetime(
        now.year, now.month, now.day, 12).astimezone(cest)

    print(cest)
    print(now)
    print(twelve_pm)
    print(twelve_pm - now)
```

for some reason, in GitHub actions, the result is:

> Europe/Berlin
>
> 2020-12-10 12:15:46.446839+01:00
>
> 2020-12-10 13:00:00+01:00
>
> 0:44:13.553161

Why does it say 13:00+01:00? I want it to say 12:00+01:00 as the function says?

Answer (score 3):

you can replace the attributes of your aware datetime object `now` as desired, e.g.

```
import datetime
import pytz

tz_Berlin = pytz.timezone('Europe/Berlin')
now = datetime.datetime.now(tz=tz_Berlin)

twelve_pm = now.replace(hour=12, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)
# datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 10, 12, 0, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Europe/Berlin' CET+1:00:00 STD>)
```

or create a datetime object representing 12 pm on the same date with localize (the correct way with `pytz`):

```
twelve_pm = tz_Berlin.localize(datetime.datetime(now.year, now.month, now.day, 12))
# datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 10, 12, 0, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Europe/Berlin' CET+1:00:00 STD>)
```

...or use Python 3.9's `zoneinfo` so you can directly set the tzinfo:

```
from zoneinfo import ZoneInfo

tz_Berlin = ZoneInfo('Europe/Berlin')
twelve_pm = datetime.datetime(now.year, now.month, now.day, 12, tzinfo=tz_Berlin)
# datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 10, 12, 0, tzinfo=zoneinfo.ZoneInfo(key='Europe/Berlin'))
```